# Are transverse and longitudinal parts of a localized current also localized?

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

The Helmholtz theorem says that any vector field $\bf{j}$ can be decomposed as
$${\bf j}={\bf j_\parallel}+{\bf j_\perp}={\bf \nabla}\phi+\operatorname{rot} {\bf A}\,\,\,\,(1)$$
The question is, if ${\bf j}$ vanishes outside some finite volume $V$, does it follow that both $\bf j_\parallel$ and $\bf j_\perp$ also vanish outside $V$? I've always assumed this to be the case, but began to doubt recently. For example, take the simplest current with a finite domain of support
$${\bf j}({\bf r})={\bf d}\,\,\delta({\bf r}) \,\,\,\,(2)$$
with some constant vector ${\bf d}$. How can it be decomposed into longitudinal and transverse parts? More importantly, will they be zero outside ${\bf r}=0$?

I ask this question here (at physics) because I'm most interested in the case when ${\bf j}$ can be interpreted as a current density. So whatever the mathematical caveats may be, I wish them to make sense physically. By the way, then the current in eq. (2) corresponds to a point dipole.

Comment: The transversal and longitudinal part will be also localized in the sense that there is no contribution at infinity. However, if you ask if they are localized in the same volume then the answer is no.

Comment: @Fabian yes, I mean localized in the same volume. Edited the question. But if what you say is true, this is counter-intuitive for two reasons (1) It's just weird! and (2) This implies that ${\bf \nabla}\phi=-{\bf \operatorname{rot} A}$ outside $V$, i.e. that the div-free field is simultaneously the curl-free filed. I think that this is in fact possible in a non-simply connected region, but I am really interested in some simple examples, where both ${\bf j}_\parallel$ and ${\bf j}_\perp$ can be constructed explicitly, and the condition ${\bf j}_\parallel=-{\bf j}_\perp$ be verified.